# JS/Canvas single line animation

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'd like to make an animation of a single line using JavaScript and Canvas tag. I'm able to do it without any problems, except:

it works fine if you're trying to do a straight line - I have an interval (10ms) adding 1px, so if it's going from 150px (x)/20px (Y) to 150px (X)/200px (Y) - everything looks cool.

Problem is with lines going to the right or left -- eg from 150px (x) / 20px (Y) to 35px (X)/200px (Y)

Here my animation fails because by adding 1px every 10ms to both X and Y makes the line hit left side (35px) first and then going from there to my end point Y.

**Here's my code** (you will need Firefox or Opera) -- as you can see line hits left side sooner and that's my problem. :(

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.prototypejs.org/assets/2008/9/29/prototype-1.6.0.3.js"></script>
<style>
body {background: #fff; color: #ccc;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var startpointx = 150;
var startpointy = 25;
var curposx = 150;
var curposy = 25;
var myinterval;

function init() {
        myinterval = setInterval( ' animate(35, 250) ', 10);
}

function random (n)
{
  return (Math.floor (Math.random() * n));
}

function animate(endpointx, endpointy) {
        if (curposx == endpointx && curposy == endpointy){
            clearInterval(myinterval);
            drawShape(endpointx, endpointy);
            return false;
        } else {

            if(curposx != endpointx){
                if(endpointx > curposx) {
                    curposx = curposx + 1;
                } else {
                    curposx = curposx - 1;
                }
            }
            if(curposy <= endpointy){
            curposy = curposy + 1;
            }
        }
    drawShape(curposx, curposy, "#000");
}

function drawShape(tendpointx, tendpointy, clor){
     var canvas = document.getElementById('cnvs');
     var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

       ctx.clearRect(0,0,310,400);
       ctx.strokeStyle = clor;
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(startpointx ,startpointy );
         ctx.lineTo(tendpointx,tendpointy);
         ctx.stroke();
}  

//  
init();

</script>


<body>
<canvas id="cnvs" width="310" height="400" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you want to draw a straight line from point (0, 0) to (100, 200). Horizontal distance is 100, vertical distance is 200, which means that when you move your end point by 1 pixel horizontally, you need to move it by 2 pixels vertically (or, for one pixel vertically 0.5 pixel horizontally).

To calculate the difference you can use this algorithm:

```
   var deltaX = Math.abs( endpointx - startpointx );
   var deltaY = Math.abs( endpointy - startpointy );
   var diffX = 1, diffY = 1;
   if( deltaX > deltaY ){
      diffY = deltaY / deltaX;
   }
   else if( deltaX < deltaY ) {
      diffX = deltaX / deltaY;
   }
```

Then in your animation you need to increment/decrement curposx and curposy not by 1, but by diffX and diffY respectively. This calculation should be done outside of your animate() function (because it always returns the same result).